# How to get the difference of two Collections?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I have two collections: collection A, collection B.

How to get the difference of two Collections in c# mongodb driver?
I would like get all items in collection A that doesn't exist in collection B.

CollectionA

```js
[
  {
    "IdCard": "123456",
    "Fullname": "Tran Van A",
    "Age": 18,
    "Address": "road a"
  },
  {
    "IdCard": "123451",
    "Fullname": "Tran Van A1",
    "Age": 16,
    "Address": "road a1"
  },
  {
    "IdCard": "123452",
    "Fullname": "Tran Van A2",
    "Age": 17,
    "Address": "road a2"
  },
  {
    "IdCard": "123453",
    "Fullname": "Tran Van A3",
    "Age": 19,
    "Address": "road a3"
  }
]
```

CollectionB

```js
[
  {
    "IdCard": "123456",
    "Fullname": "Tran Van A",
    "Age": 18,
    "Address": "road a"
  },
  {
    "IdCard": "123451",
    "Fullname": "Tran Van A1",
    "Age": 16,
    "Address": "road a1"
  },
  {
    "IdCard": "123455",
    "Fullname": "Tran Van B1",
    "Age": 16,
    "Address": "road b2"
  },
  {
    "IdCard": "123455",
    "Fullname": "Tran Van B3",
    "Age": 19,
    "Address": "road B3"
  }
]
```

Expected Result

```js
[
  {
    "IdCard": "123452",
    "Fullname": "Tran Van A2",
    "Age": 17,
    "Address": "road a2"
  },
  {
    "IdCard": "123453",
    "Fullname": "Tran Van A3",
    "Age": 19,
    "Address": "road a3"
  }
]
```

Comment: can you be more specific? compare those collections based on what creteria? and what fileds each collection has, and what output you want?

Comment: I would like get all items in collection A not exist in collection B

Answer (score 0):

Query

- adds a field to collectionA `coll:0` to know that those documents belong to A
- union with collectionB and add a field also to `coll:1` to know that those documents belong to B (0= from A , 1= from B)
- group by `IdCard` and colls with `addtoset` those fields we added
- a document bellong only to the first collection, if `size(colls)==1`
  (didnt belong to both) and also it belonged to the first its tested with `$in`
- now we have the difference of the collections
- replace root/unset to restore the original doc structure of collectionA

*query assumes that if IdCard is the same all document will be the same, if this is not the case, you can group by more fields, or even all fields

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/play/?q=71389703-m)

```js
colla.aggregate(
[{"$set":{"coll":0}},
 {"$unionWith":{"coll":"collb", "pipeline":[{"$set":{"coll":1}}]}},
 {"$group":
  {"_id":"$IdCard",
   "doc":{"$first":"$$ROOT"},
   "colls":{"$addToSet":"$coll"}}},
 {"$match":
  {"$expr":
   {"$and":
    [{"$eq":[{"$size":"$colls"}, 1]}, {"$in":[0, "$colls"]}]}}},
 {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$doc"}},
 {"$unset":["coll"]}])
```

Comment: good it helped, accept the answer and upvote if it helped you, this increase users reputation, and helps other people to know which answers worked, which were useful etc